# Performance Using MYSQL Views by Joining Two Large Tables

Tags: mysql, left-join, view

I have two tables that have ~100M rows. I created a view by:

```
CREATE VIEW listView 
AS 
SELECT
  a.tID as a_tID,
  b.tID as b_tID,
  a.anothercolumn as a_anothercolumn,
  b.anothercolumn as b_anothercolumn
FROM tab1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 b ON a.tID=b.tID;
```

Is this an efficient usage of Views for such a large table?

**Note:** Both the tables are indexed on tID.

Comment: In MySQL, an efficient use of views is to not use views. Why? Because queries against MySQL's views cannot (presently) use indexes.

Comment: Try MariaDB: View behavior seems to be better.